# Terminate shell code while it is running

Tags: shell, scripting, ascii, terminate

For clearing screen in shell code if we write CTRL + L we do

```
printf "\033c"
```

then what shall be done for CTRL + C ?

just `exit` is not working in my code because i am handling errors and in case of bad inputs i have to run code again and for that when i am `unseting` variables by `unset` it is working fine but later again my code shows output with no input variables.

Comment: I think that CTRL+C is a command that triggers a signal and you can't emulate it printing something on the screen. Why you can't use just `exit`?

Comment: @wooghie- I have edited my question. Please have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you should use the `trap` command. `trap` prevent the shell default handling and allows you to interrupt, quit, hangup etc. what you were doing.

The syntax is the following

```
trap <command to execute> <signal to intercept>
```

so you could do something like

```
trap break INT
```

to have the equivalent of a Ctrl-C.